# Android alarm_manager_plus Package not working

Tags: flutter, dart, notifications

i try to use android_alarm_manager_plus: ^3.0.3 for flutter app(Flutter 3.13.1) to make my notification runs on background/when the app is terminate.but the android manager is not working to show my notif(i've try the local notif by itself and its work so its not the notif)
here my code

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await AndroidAlarmManager.initialize();
  runApp(MyApp());
...

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    var initializationSettingsAndroid =
        AndroidInitializationSettings('@mipmap/ic_launcher');
    var initializationSettings =
        InitializationSettings(android: initializationSettingsAndroid);
    flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin = FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();
    flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(initializationSettings);
    _startAlarm();
  }

  void _startAlarm() {
    print('start.');
    
    Timer(Duration(minutes: 1), () {
      print('already 1 minute bruhh');
    });
    AndroidAlarmManager.periodic(Duration(minutes: 1), 0, _showNotification,
        wakeup: true);
  }

@pragma('vm:entry-point')
  void _showNotification() async {
    print('showing..');
    var androidPlatformChannelSpecifics = AndroidNotificationDetails(
      'your channel id',
      'your channel name',
      importance: Importance.max,
      priority: Priority.high,
    );
    var platformChannelSpecifics =
        NotificationDetails(android: androidPlatformChannelSpecifics);
    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
      0,
      'Hello, world',
      'This is a local notification',
      platformChannelSpecifics,
      payload: 'item x',
    );
  }
}
```

i've follow the instructure in the docs to add this in android manifest but it didn't work

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM"/>
...
<service
    android:name="dev.fluttercommunity.plus.androidalarmmanager.AlarmService"
    android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE"
    android:exported="false"/>
<receiver
    android:name="dev.fluttercommunity.plus.androidalarmmanager.AlarmBroadcastReceiver"
    android:exported="false"/>
<receiver
    android:name="dev.fluttercommunity.plus.androidalarmmanager.RebootBroadcastReceiver"
    android:enabled="false"
    android:exported="false">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

almost forgot i also add this
        `classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.8.0"`
i see it from the stackoverflow too when i face error